# `[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]` in (C) free function always returns same value

Tags: ios, nsdate, compiler-optimization

If I have:

```
double now_ms() {
    return 1000 * (float)[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
};

:
    NSLog( @"%f", now_ms() ); // inside a CADisplayLink tick-event
```

It gives the same value each time.

I can fix this by making a Lambda:

```
double (^now_ms)(void) = ^() {
    return 1000.f * [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
};
NSLog( @"%f", now_ms() ); // works!
```

However I would prefer it to be a free function.

What is going on?

I suspect this is some kind of run-time optimisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that [`NSTimeInterval`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nstimeinterval?language=occ) (which is what [`timeIntervalSince1970`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdate/1407504-timeintervalsince1970?language=objc) returns) is a `double` and you’re casting it to a `float`. But `float` can only capture roughly 7 significant digits. That’s not nearly accurate enough to capture the number of seconds since 1970, much less the number of milliseconds.

Your lambda solution works simply because you removed the `float` cast. You can do the same with your function:

```
double now_ms() {
    return 1000.0 * [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
}
```